# Store single result as List<> from loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please check Part1 carefully. The variable "singleItem" containing the item during loop of each Ids. But my goal is convert this "singleItem" variable as a List of items. So i can use this "singleItem" in another method like Part2

Part1:

```
foreach (int Id in Ids)
{
    var singleItem = ctx.SingleScannedItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SingleScannedItemId == Id);
}
```

Part2:

```
public string MyMethod(List<singleItem> items)
{
    //do something with items
}
```

Comment: What is Ids? is it an in memory collection? With what db are you working?

Comment: Ids are the array of SingleScannedItemId collection

Comment: Can two different `SingleScannedItem` have the same `SingleScannedItemId`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains` method to query all the items which has `SingleScannedItemId` property value matching to the values in the `Ids` collection.

```
var filteredItems = ctx.SingleScannedItems
                       .Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.SingleScannedItemId)).ToList();
```

You do not need the loop now as you are querying all those items you wanted once.

The variable `filteredItems` will be a list of `SingleScannedItem`. You can pass that to a method which accepts the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need loop , checking against a **`Ids`** list the following would work.

```
List<singleItem> items = ctx.SingleScannedItems
                .Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.SingleScannedItemId).ToList();

MyMethod(items);
```